# WPF DataGrid and IAsyncEnumerable items

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-5

Is it possible?
How?

I have an asynchronous method fetching rows of data from my database.
My result is `IAsyncEnumerable<TItem>`.
It should be a perfect data type for a fast and responsive UI, however - when I set it as a datasource for my grid it just doesn't work and shows nothing.

I have 2 workarounds for this. First is obviously to return array from my async task. The second one is similar - I can just use `ToArrayAsync()` on result (from `System.Linq.Async`).

I suspect that using `ToArrayAsync()` is slower than just returning the array from the task, so it doesn't make much sense.

It would make a lot of sense if `IAsyncEnumerable` type could be used directly as a data source for the control. But then I probably need to implement some kind of `IObservable` interface or something like that. Did anyone tried this?

The whole thing is pretty new and I can't find any examples, or even an article stating that it's even possible. I mean - what good `IAsyncEnumerable` is if you cannot use it for the UI?

Update: what I'm looking for is a conversion between `IAsyncEnumerable<TItem>` and `ObservableCollection<TItem>`. I found examples, but they all work exactly as my mentioned workaround - so the data is put into an array and then added to the collection. This defeats all `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` benefits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IAsyncEnumerable` is introduced to allow async data generators/data streams. Usually controls like `ItemsControl` that display a collection of data items are index based. And `ICollectionView` based.

Usually the control gets the items via the `ICollectionView` of the original collection. A data item, identified by its index in the source collection's `ICollectionView`, is wrapped into an `UIElement` container for rendering.
A data stream/generator is not index based. An `Enumerator` (result of a call to `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator`) is used to step from element to element by invoking `IEnumerator.MoveNext` (`foreach` is a language construct that for convenience encapsulates the actual enumeration logic that involves the `IEnumerator`).
Aside from potential threading problems introduced by an async data stream, the index based `ItemsControl` needs to know all it's items in advance - that's why you need a collection that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` in order to have the `ItemsControl` update its `Items` on changes: the View is considered to be passive - it only displays data and does not generate the data.
Although not mandatory, WPF was designed with MVVM in mind. The active part is usually the Model or the View Model. Data generation would usually take place in the Model. So, it does not make sense to have `IAsyncEnumerable` as direct binding source as this would mean that the passive UI element must generate/consume the data stream directly. You would want this to be a responsibility of the View Model/`Binding.Source`. And again, the UI is designed to work on `ICollectionView` implementations and not on collections and their iterators directly.

What you can do is to enumerate the `IAsyncEnumerable` in the `Binding.Source` and update an `ObservableCollection` with the generated results:

```
public ObservableCollection<DataItem> ItemsSourceForDataGrid { get; }

private async Task GenerateDataItemsAsync(IAsyncEnumerable asyncDataStream)
{
  // Keep the GUI responsive while consuming an e.g. CPU intensive generator
  await foreach (DataItem item in asyncDataStream)
  {
    this.ItemsSourceForDataGrid.Add(item);
  }
}
```

Also note that extension methods like `ToListAsync` and `ToArrayAsync` can potentially lock the application. If you don't know the data source i.e. the generator you risk to lock your application as `ToListAsync` tries to finalize the data stream. But per definition a data stream can be infinite which would cause `ToListAsync` to never return or complete the returned `Task` object. If you find yourself in the need of `ToArrayAsync` and you are the author of the data generator, you probably should not use `IAsyncEnumerable` in the first place. Asynchronous finalizers like `ToArrayAsync` defy the idea of `IAsyncEnumerable`.

Comment: Your hint works as charm in my app. After implementing adding items to the `ObservableCollection` asynchronously and triggering `OnCollectionChanged()` on each item my UI works significantly faster, the views are populated IMMEDIATELY. It because the visible rows are fetched way earlier than all the data finishes loading. It is significant and VISIBLE improvement over the synchronous version. So it was very worth it. Thank you good sir!

Comment: BTW, my `ObservableCollection` is created and populated in my view model. So - the model returns `IAsyncEnumerable`, it produces an item each time a row is read from the database. Then my view model creates the `ObservableCollection` and populates it asynchronously. The view just consumes the collection from view model and updates while still loading. I made no changes to the view.

Comment: Yes, your data flow is perfect. You now make perfect use of asynchronous iterators to feed your UI with a stream of data.